# Bing maps beta error in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps

Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: Have you tried registering the class...?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the final build [which has just recently been made available](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca)